# The content property of EmberController should be set before modifying it

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ember.js

What's wrong here?

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The content property of
>   App.ContactController should be set before modifying it

```
App.ContactController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  content: []

  newContact: ->
    contact = App.ContactModel.create
      firstName: "john"
      lastName: "doe"
    @.pushObject contact
```

Answer (score 3):

Place `this.set('content', []);` above your `pushObject` and it will work fine. I don't quite understand why this is a requirement, but it appears to be in pre 4. Perhaps in the next release they'll consider `pushObject` *setting* it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a CoffeeScript syntax issue; try removing the dot: `@pushObject contact`